# why updating sys.path is not effecting the list of directories python will search

Tags: python

I am trying to import serial module. But it was throwing error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RawIOBase'
```

Later I found that there is one more directory with name 'io' and 'init.py' file exists in the directory. so when I print using print(io), it is displaying

```
<module 'io' from '/projects/phx/tools/io/__init__.pyc'>
```

instead of

```
<module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/io.pyc'>
```

To update PYTHONPATH, I used below line in my program

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib64/python2.6")
```

After this, I am importing serial as below.

```
exec("import serial")
```

but it didn't solve the problem. I am getting the same error.

If I add `"/usr/lib64/python2.6"` to PYTHONPATH in bashrc file, it is working fine.

Can any one please help me to understand why sys.path is not effecting the list of directories python will search?

Comment: All of that `pythonpath` stuff you are doing seems useless, just modify `sys.path` if you need. And why `exec` instead of a regular `import` statement?

Comment: @LevLevitsky sorry. I edited the question now.I do agree that exec is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you can join your system path together using

```
>>> ':'.join(sys.path)
'/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7'
```

But you shouldn't be setting the `env['PYTHONPATH']` as you were doing.

All you need to do is edit your system path like this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib64/python2.6")
```

Any imports after this line will look at `/usr/lib64/python2.6` first.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib64/python2.6")
import serial
```

Comment: Martin, I did the same thing. But it seems it has no effect. I updated the question also.

Comment: Ok. If I do the changes outside of all the functions, it is working fine. But if I write the code inside any function, it is throwing the error. Any idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Yes, you need to do this at the top of your module that Python first loads.